# Plotly Map not showing

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly

As you can see here https://www.kaggle.com/asindico/exploratory-analysis I am trying to plot a world map through plotly but the maps is not shown. Any advice would be appreciated

here is the related chunk of code

```
w_data = [ dict(
        type = 'choropleth',
        locations = data['Country'].value_counts().index,
        z = data['Country'].value_counts(),
        locationmode = 'country names',
        text = data['Country'].value_counts().index,
        marker = dict(
            line = dict(color = 'rgb(0,0,0)', width = 1)),
            colorbar = dict(tickprefix = '', 
            title = 'World map')
            )
       ]

layout = dict(
    title = 'World map',
    width = 20,
    height = 15,
    geo = dict(
        showframe = False,
        showocean = True,
        oceancolor = 'rgb(0,255,255)',
        projection = dict(
        type = 'orthographic',
            rotation = dict(
                    lon = 60,
                    lat = 10),
        ),
        lonaxis =  dict(
                showgrid = True,
                gridcolor = 'rgb(102, 102, 102)'
            ),
        lataxis = dict(
                showgrid = True,
                gridcolor = 'rgb(102, 102, 102)'
                )
            ),
        )

fig = dict(data=w_data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

it belongs to a Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the line:

```
init_notebook_mode(connected = True)
```

You need this line to display graphs in a jupyter notebook.